# GROUP BY inside GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL @ MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've got a query (those 2 tables inside of it are a little bit complicated so that's why I don't want to describe them-I will do that in the simpliest way below) with a GROUP_CONCAT, but I've got repeating values in the output row that I don't want.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(mr.nazwa SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM
    mp06_logos.milkruny AS mr
JOIN
    mp06_logos.milkruny_firmy AS mrf
    ON mrf.id_milkrun = mr.id
WHERE
    mr.status = 1
    AND mrf.id_firmy_zaladunku = 5445
    AND mrf.adres_firmy_zaladunku = 5188
```

And the output row is:

```
Milkrun XVI, Milkrun XVI, Milkrun XVI, Milkrun XVI, Milkrun XVII, Milkrun XVII, Milkrun XVII, Milkrun XVIII, Milkrun XIX, Milkrun XIX, Milkrun XIX, Milkrun XX, Milkrun XX, Milkrun XX, Milkrun XXI, Milkrun XXII, Milkrun XXII, Milkrun XXII, Milkrun XXII, Milkrun XXIII, Milkrun XXIII, Milkrun XXIII, Milkrun XXIII, Milkrun XXIII, Milkrun XXIII, Milkrun XXIII, Milkrun XXIII, Milkrun XXI
```

As you can see in the output I've got for example: Milkrun XVI repeated 4 times.

I was trying to add `GROUP BY` some id's of the query but that just caused more problems and this query up is the most similar to what I want.

I just don't want to repeat values inside the output.

Table `milkruny` has `UNIQUE` column `id`.

Table `milkruny_firmy` has `UNIQUE` column `id`, columns `id_milkrun` and the rest are not `UNIQUE` and they don't have any other `key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mr.nazwa SEPARATOR ', ')
```

Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/867089/1

Comment: Great! Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome!! If you got your answer you can accept and upvote

Comment: I have to wait until I can accept. Also u can vote up my question :)